# Is there an efficient algorithm for this quadratic constraint problem?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, quadratic-programming

I have a problem that can be formulated as a quadratic constraint program with $O(n^3)$ constraints and $O(n)$ variables, which are grouped into $O(n)$ vectors of size 2. The constraints are all of the form $s((x_j-x_i)\cdot(x_k-x_i))\geq0$ where $s\in\{-1,1\}$ and the $x_i,x_j,x_k$ are distinct vectors of variables. Is there a way to take advantage of this special structure to get a more efficient solution to the problem than general quadratic constraint programs?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @david scholz I am trying to take a set of constraints of the form “point pi is to the left/right of the directed line from pj to pk” and decide if there is a set of points that realizes these constraints.

Comment: EDIT: Realized this was actually not linear, but rather quadratic. I wonder if there is a even a polynomial time solution at this point?..